# Help with regex/preg_replace expression to exclude JS from compression routine

Tags: php, jquery, regex, preg-replace

hopefully this should be an easy one.

I am using this code in my codeigniter app to strip whitespaces et al. (via Jerome Jaglale) -- [link](http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_compress_html).

```
function compress()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $buffer = $CI->output->get_output();

    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',
        '/(\s)+/s', // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
        '#(?://)?<!\[CDATA\[(.*?)(?://)?\]\]>#s' //leave CDATA alone
    );
    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1',
        "//&lt;![CDATA[\n".'\1'."\n//]]>"
    );

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);

    $CI->output->set_output($buffer);
    $CI->output->_display();
}
```

The issue is that I need to exclude my inline jQuery from this compression routine. My jQuery is always within `<script></script>` tags but this code is considering the use of `<![CDATA[]]>` (lines 10 and 16).

I've tried tweaking this so that instead of `CDATA` the routine excludes `<script>` but just can't get it right.

Anyone care to show me the light?

BTW, as you can see I do not use the `CDATA` tag nor `<script type="text/javascript">` -- so if you think this is absolutely necessary, maybe the regex I need should reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here:

http://www.enapupe.com.br/blog/65/codeigniter-minify-html-output/

This works very well and is not breaking my jQuery.

Essentially this is a CI library adapted from the Minify project that is used for W3 Total Cache and Wp-minify (Wordpress plugins).

Answer (score 0):

I use this trick for minify output html, css & js in codeigniter :

```
function compress() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->output->set_output(Minifyhtml::minify($CI->output->get_output(), array('is_xhtml'=>null, 'js_clean_comments'=>false, 'cssMinifier'=>'Minify_CSS::minify', 'jsMinifier'=>'Minify_JS::minify')));
    $CI->output->_display();
}

class Minifyhtml {
    protected $is_xhtml             = null;
    protected $js_clean_comments    = true;
    protected $replacement_hash     = null;
    protected $placeholders         = array();
    protected $css_minifier         = null;
    protected $js_minifier          = null;
    public static function minify($html, $options = array()) {
        $min = new self($html, $options);
        return $min->process();
    }
    public function __construct($html, $options = array()) {
        $this->html = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", trim($html));
        $this->html = str_replace("\r\r", "\n", $this->html);
        $this->html = str_replace("\n\n", "\n", $this->html);
        if(isset($options['is_xhtml'])) { $this->is_xhtml = (bool)$options['is_xhtml']; }
        if(isset($options['js_clean_comments'])) { $this->js_clean_comments = (bool)$options['js_clean_comments']; }
        if(isset($options['cssMinifier'])) { $this->css_minifier = $options['cssMinifier']; }
        if(isset($options['jsMinifier'])) { $this->js_minifier = $options['jsMinifier']; }
    }
    public function process() {
        if ($this->is_xhtml === null) { $this->is_xhtml = (false !== strpos($this->html, '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML')); }
        $this->replacement_hash = 'MINIFYHTML' . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
        $this->placeholders = array();
        $this->html = preg_replace_callback('/(\\s*)<script(\\b[^>]*?>)([\\s\\S]*?)<\\/script>(\\s*)/i', array($this, 'removeScriptCB'), $this->html);
        $this->html = preg_replace_callback('/\\s*<style(\\b[^>]*>)([\\s\\S]*?)<\\/style>\\s*/i', array($this, 'removeStyleCB'), $this->html);
        $this->html = preg_replace_callback('/<!--([\\s\\S]*?)-->/', array($this, 'commentCB'), $this->html);
        $this->html = preg_replace_callback('/\\s*<pre(\\b[^>]*?>[\\s\\S]*?<\\/pre>)\\s*/i', array($this, 'removePreCB'), $this->html);
        $this->html = preg_replace_callback('/\\s*<textarea(\\b[^>]*?>[\\s\\S]*?<\\/textarea>)\\s*/i', array($this, 'removeTextareaCB'), $this->html);
        $this->html = preg_replace('/^\\s+|\\s+$/m', '', $this->html);
        $this->html = preg_replace('/\\s+(<\\/?(?:area|base(?:font)?|blockquote|body|caption|center|cite|col(?:group)?|dd|dir|div|dl|dt|fieldset|form|frame(?:set)?|h[1-6]|head|hr|html|legend|li|link|map|menu|meta|ol|opt(?:group|ion)|p|param|t(?:able|body|head|d|h||r|foot|itle)|ul)\\b[^>]*>)/i', '$1', $this->html);
        $this->html = preg_replace('/>(\\s(?:\\s*))?([^<]+)(\\s(?:\s*))?</', '>$1$2$3<', $this->html);
        $this->html = preg_replace('/(<[a-z\\-]+)\\s+([^>]+>)/i', "$1 $2", $this->html);
        $this->html = str_replace(array_keys($this->placeholders), array_values($this->placeholders), $this->html);
        $this->html = str_replace(array_keys($this->placeholders), array_values($this->placeholders), $this->html);
        return $this->html;
    }
    protected function commentCB($m) { return (0 === strpos($m[1], '[') || false !== strpos($m[1], '<!['))?$m[0]:''; }
    protected function reservePlace($content) {
        $placeholder = '%' . $this->replacement_hash . count($this->placeholders) . '%';
        $this->placeholders[$placeholder] = $content;
        return $placeholder;
    }
    protected function removePreCB($m) { return $this->reservePlace("<pre{$m[1]}"); }
    protected function removeTextareaCB($m) { return $this->reservePlace("<textarea{$m[1]}"); }
    protected function removeStyleCB($m) {
        $open_style = "<style{$m[1]}";
        $css        = $m[2];
        $css        = preg_replace('/(?:^\\s*<!--|-->\\s*$)/', '', $css);
        $css        = $this->removeCdata($css);
        $minifier   = $this->css_minifier?$this->css_minifier:'trim';
        $css        = call_user_func($minifier, $css);
        return $this->reservePlace($this->needsCdata($css)?"{$open_style}/*<![CDATA[*/{$css}/*]]>*/</style>":"{$open_style}{$css}</style>");
    }
    protected function removeScriptCB($m) {
        $open_script    = "<script{$m[2]}";
        $js             = $m[3];
        $ws1            = ($m[1] === '')?'':' ';
        $ws2            = ($m[4] === '')?'':' ';
        if($this->js_clean_comments) { $js = preg_replace('/(?:^\\s*<!--\\s*|\\s*(?:\\/\\/)?\\s*-->\\s*$)/', '', $js); }
        $js             = $this->removeCdata($js);
        $minifier       = $this->js_minifier?$this->js_minifier:'trim';
        $js             = call_user_func($minifier, $js);
        return $this->reservePlace($this->needsCdata($js)?"{$ws1}{$open_script}/*<![CDATA[*/{$js}/*]]>*/</script>{$ws2}":"{$ws1}{$open_script}{$js}</script>{$ws2}");
    }
    protected function removeCdata($str) { return (false !== strpos($str, '<![CDATA['))?str_replace(array('<![CDATA[', ']]>'), '', $str):$str; }
    protected function needsCdata($str) { return ($this->is_xhtml && preg_match('/(?:[<&]|\\-\\-|\\]\\]>)/', $str)); }
}

class Minify_CSS {
    protected $in_hack = false;
    public static function minify($css) {
        $min = new self($css);
        return $min->process();
    }
    private function __construct($css) {
        $this->css = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $css);
        $this->css = str_replace("\r\r", "\n", $this->css);
        $this->css = str_replace("\n\n", "\n", $this->css);
    }
    protected function process() {
        $this->css = preg_replace('@>/\\*\\s*\\*/@', '>/*keep*/', $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace('@/\\*\\s*\\*/\\s*:@', '/*keep*/:', $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace('@:\\s*/\\*\\s*\\*/@', ':/*keep*/', $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace_callback('@\\s*/\\*([\\s\\S]*?)\\*/\\s*@', array($this, 'commentCB'), $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace('/\\s*{\\s*/', '{', $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace('/;?\\s*}\\s*/', '}', $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace('/\\s*;\\s*/', ';', $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace('/
                url\\(      # url(
                \\s*
                ([^\\)]+?)  # 1 = the URL (really just a bunch of non right parenthesis)
                \\s*
                \\)         # )
            /x', 'url($1)', $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace('/
                \\s*
                ([{;])              # 1 = beginning of block or rule separator
                \\s*
                ([\\*_]?[\\w\\-]+)  # 2 = property (and maybe IE filter)
                \\s*
                :
                \\s*
                (\\b|[#\'"-])        # 3 = first character of a value
            /x', '$1$2:$3', $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace_callback('/
                (?:              # non-capture
                    \\s*
                    [^~>+,\\s]+  # selector part
                    \\s*
                    [,>+~]       # combinators
                )+
                \\s*
                [^~>+,\\s]+      # selector part
                {                # open declaration block
            /x', array($this, 'selectorsCB'), $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace('/([^=])#([a-f\\d])\\2([a-f\\d])\\3([a-f\\d])\\4([\\s;\\}])/i', '$1#$2$3$4$5', $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace_callback('/font-family:([^;}]+)([;}])/', array($this, 'fontFamilyCB'), $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace('/@import\\s+url/', '@import url', $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace('/[ \\t]*\\n+\\s*/', "\n", $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace('/([\\w#\\.\\*]+)\\s+([\\w#\\.\\*]+){/', "$1\n$2{", $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace('/
            ((?:padding|margin|border|outline):\\d+(?:px|em)?) # 1 = prop : 1st numeric value
            \\s+
            /x'
                ,"$1 ", $this->css);
        $this->css = preg_replace('/:first-l(etter|ine)\\{/', ':first-l$1 {', $this->css);
        return trim($this->css);
    }
    protected function selectorsCB($m) { return preg_replace('/\\s*([,>+~])\\s*/', '$1', $m[0]); }
    protected function commentCB($m) {
        $has_surrounding_ws = (trim($m[0]) !== $m[1]);
        $m                  = $m[1];
        if ($m === 'keep') { return '/**/'; }
        if ($m === '" "') { return '/*" "*/'; }
        if (preg_match('@";\\}\\s*\\}/\\*\\s+@', $m)) { return '/*";}}/* */'; }
        if ($this->in_hack) {
            if (preg_match('@
                    ^/               # comment started like /*/
                    \\s*
                    (\\S[\\s\\S]+?)  # has at least some non-ws content
                    \\s*
                    /\\*             # ends like /*/ or /**/
                @x', $m, $n)) {
                $this->in_hack = false;
                return "/*/{$n[1]}/**/";
            }
        }
        if (substr($m, -1) === '\\') {
            $this->in_hack = true;
            return '/*\\*/';
        }
        if ($m !== '' && $m[0] === '/') {
            $this->in_hack = true;
            return '/*/*/';
        }
        if ($this->in_hack) {
            $this->in_hack = false;
            return '/**/';
        }
        return $has_surrounding_ws?' ':'';
    }
    protected function fontFamilyCB($m) {
        $pieces = preg_split('/(\'[^\']+\'|"[^"]+")/', $m[1], null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $out    = 'font-family:';
        while (null !== ($piece = array_shift($pieces))) {
            if ($piece[0] !== '"' && $piece[0] !== "'") {
                $piece = preg_replace('/\\s+/', ' ', $piece);
                $piece = preg_replace('/\\s?,\\s?/', ',', $piece);
            }
            $out .= $piece;
        }
        return $out . $m[2];
    }
}

class Minify_JS {
    const IGNORE                = '$1';
    private $script             = '';
    private $encoding           = 62;
    private $fast_decode        = true;
    private $special_chars      = false;
    private $LITERAL_ENCODING   = array(
            'None'          => 0,
            'Numeric'       => 10,
            'Normal'        => 62,
            'High ASCII'    => 95
    );
    private $parsers            = array();
    private $word_count         = array();
    const JSFUNCTION_unpack =
    'function($packed, $ascii, $count, $keywords, $encode, $decode) {
    while ($count--) {
        if ($keywords[$count]) {
            $packed = $packed.replace(new RegExp(\'\\\\b\' + $encode($count) + \'\\\\b\', \'g\'), $keywords[$count]);
        }
    }
    return $packed;
    }';
    const JSFUNCTION_decodeBody =
    '    if (!\'\'.replace(/^/, String)) {
        // decode all the values we need
        while ($count--) {
            $decode[$encode($count)] = $keywords[$count] || $encode($count);
        }
        // global replacement function
        $keywords = [function ($encoded) {return $decode[$encoded]}];
        // generic match
        $encode = function () {return \'\\\\w+\'};
        // reset the loop counter -  we are now doing a global replace
        $count = 1;
    }
    ';
    const JSFUNCTIONencode10    = 'function($char_code) { return $char_code; }';
    const JSFUNCTIONencode36    = 'function($char_code) { return $char_code.toString(36); }';
    const JSFUNCTIONencode62    = 'function($char_code) { return ($char_code < _encoding ? \'\' : arguments.callee(parseInt($char_code / _encoding))) + (($char_code = $char_code % _encoding) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode($char_code + 29) : $char_code.toString(36)); }';
    const JSFUNCTIONencode95    = 'function($char_code) { return ($char_code < _encoding ? \'\' : arguments.callee($char_code / _encoding)) + String.fromCharCode($char_code % _encoding + 161); }';
    private $buffer;
    public static function minify($script) {
        $min = new self($script);
        return $min->process();
    }
    public function __construct($script, $encoding = 62, $fast_decode = true, $special_chars = false) {
        $this->script           = $script . "\n";
        if (array_key_exists($encoding, $this->LITERAL_ENCODING)) { $encoding = $this->LITERAL_ENCODING[$encoding]; }
        $this->encoding         = min((int)$encoding, 95);
        $this->fast_decode      = $fast_decode;
        $this->special_chars    = $special_chars;
    }
    public function process() {
        $this->addParser('basicCompression');
        if ($this->special_chars) { $this->addParser('encodeSpecialChars'); }
        if ($this->encoding) { $this->addParser('encodeKeywords'); }
        return $this->pack($this->script);
    }
    private function pack($script) {
        for ($i = 0; isset($this->parsers[$i]); $i++) { $script = call_user_func(array(&$this, $this->parsers[$i]), $script); }
        return $script;
    }
    private function addParser($parser) { $this->parsers[] = $parser; }
    private function basicCompression($script) {
        $parser = new ParseMaster();
        $parser->escapeChar = '\\';
        $parser->add('/\'[^\'\\n\\r]*\'/', self::IGNORE);
        $parser->add('/"[^"\\n\\r]*"/', self::IGNORE);
        $parser->add('/\\/\\/[^\\n\\r]*[\\n\\r]/', ' ');
        $parser->add('/\\/\\*[^*]*\\*+([^\\/][^*]*\\*+)*\\//', ' ');
        $parser->add('/\\s+(\\/[^\\/\\n\\r\\*][^\\/\\n\\r]*\\/g?i?)/', '$2');
        $parser->add('/[^\\w\\x24\\/\'"*)\\?:]\\/[^\\/\\n\\r\\*][^\\/\\n\\r]*\\/g?i?/', self::IGNORE);
        if ($this->special_chars) $parser->add('/;;;[^\\n\\r]+[\\n\\r]/');
        $parser->add('/\\(;;\\)/', self::IGNORE);
        $parser->add('/;+\\s*([};])/', '$2');
        $script = $parser->exec($script);
        $parser->add('/(\\b|\\x24)\\s+(\\b|\\x24)/', '$2 $3');
        $parser->add('/([+\\-])\\s+([+\\-])/', '$2 $3');
        $parser->add('/\\s+/', '');
        return $parser->exec($script);
    }
    private function encodeSpecialChars($script) {
        $parser     = new ParseMaster();
        $parser->add('/((\\x24+)([a-zA-Z$_]+))(\\d*)/', array('fn' => 'replace_name') );
        $regexp     = '/\\b_[A-Za-z\\d]\\w*/';
        $keywords   = $this->_analyze($script, $regexp, 'encodePrivate');
        $encoded    = $keywords['encoded'];
        $parser->add($regexp, array('fn' => 'replace_encoded', 'data' => $encoded));
        return $parser->exec($script);
    }
    private function encodeKeywords($script) {
        if ($this->encoding > 62) { $script = $this->escape95($script); }
        $parser     = new ParseMaster();
        $encode     = $this->getEncoder($this->encoding);
        $regexp     = ($this->encoding > 62) ? '/\\w\\w+/' : '/\\w+/';
        $keywords   = $this->_analyze($script, $regexp, $encode);
        $encoded    = $keywords['encoded'];
        $parser->add($regexp, array('fn' => 'replace_encoded', 'data' => $encoded));
        if (empty($script)) { return $script; } else { return $this->bootStrap($parser->exec($script), $keywords); }
    }
    private function _analyze($script, $regexp, $encode) {
        $all        = array();
        preg_match_all($regexp, $script, $all);
        $sorted     = array();
        $encoded    = array();
        $protected  = array();
        $all        = $all[0];
        if (!empty($all)) {
            $unsorted           = array();
            $protected          = array();
            $value              = array();
            $this->word_count   = array();
            $i                  = count($all); $j = 0;
            do {
                --$i;
                $word = '$' . $all[$i];
                if (!isset($this->word_count[$word])) {
                    $this->word_count[$word]    = 0;
                    $unsorted[$j]               = $word;
                    $values[$j]                 = call_user_func(array(&$this, $encode), $j);
                    $protected['$' . $values[$j]] = $j++;
                }
                $this->word_count[$word]++;
            } while ($i > 0);
            $i = count($unsorted);
            do {
                $word = $unsorted[--$i];
                if (isset($protected[$word])) {
                    $sorted[$protected[$word]]      = substr($word, 1);
                    $protected[$protected[$word]]   = true;
                    $this->word_count[$word]        = 0;
                }
            } while ($i);
            usort($unsorted, array(&$this, 'sortWords'));
            $j = 0;
            do {
                if (!isset($sorted[$i])) { $sorted[$i] = substr($unsorted[$j++], 1); }
                $encoded[$sorted[$i]] = $values[$i];
            } while (++$i < count($unsorted));
        }
        return array('sorted'  => $sorted, 'encoded' => $encoded, 'protected' => $protected);
    }

    private function sortWords($match1, $match2) { return $this->word_count[$match2] - $this->word_count[$match1]; }
    private function bootStrap($packed, $keywords) {
        $ENCODE     = $this->safeRegExp('$encode\\($count\\)');
        $packed     = "'" . $this->escape($packed) . "'";
        $ascii      = min(count($keywords['sorted']), $this->encoding);
        if ($ascii == 0) { $ascii = 1; }
        $count      = count($keywords['sorted']);
        foreach ($keywords['protected'] as $i=>$value) { $keywords['sorted'][$i] = ''; }
        ksort($keywords['sorted']);
        $keywords   = "'" . implode('|',$keywords['sorted']) . "'.split('|')";
        $encode = ($this->encoding > 62) ? 'encode95' : $this->getEncoder($ascii);
        $encode = $this->getJSFunction($encode);
        $encode = preg_replace('/_encoding/','$ascii', $encode);
        $encode = preg_replace('/arguments\\.callee/','$encode', $encode);
        $inline = '\\$count' . ($ascii > 10 ? '.toString(\\$ascii)' : '');
        if ($this->fast_decode) {
            $decode = $this->getJSFunction('_decodeBody');
            if ($this->encoding > 62) { $decode = preg_replace('/\\\\w/', '[\\xa1-\\xff]', $decode); } elseif ($ascii < 36) { $decode = preg_replace($ENCODE, $inline, $decode); }
            if ($count == 0) { $decode = preg_replace($this->safeRegExp('($count)\\s*=\\s*1'), '$1=0', $decode, 1); }
        }
        $unpack = $this->getJSFunction('_unpack');
        if ($this->fast_decode) {
            $this->buffer = $decode;
            $unpack = preg_replace_callback('/\\{/', array(&$this, 'insertFastDecode'), $unpack, 1);
        }
        $unpack = preg_replace('/"/', "'", $unpack);
        if ($this->encoding > 62) { $unpack = preg_replace('/\'\\\\\\\\b\'\s*\\+|\\+\s*\'\\\\\\\\b\'/', '', $unpack); }
        if ($ascii > 36 || $this->encoding > 62 || $this->fast_decode) {
            $this->buffer = $encode;
            $unpack = preg_replace_callback('/\\{/', array(&$this, 'insertFastEncode'), $unpack, 1);
        } else { $unpack = preg_replace($ENCODE, $inline, $unpack); }
        $unpack_packer  = new Minify_JS($unpack, 0, false, true);
        $unpack         = $unpack_packer->process();

        $params         = array($packed, $ascii, $count, $keywords);
        if ($this->fast_decode) {
            $params[] = 0;
            $params[] = '{}';
        }
        $params = implode(',', $params);
        return 'eval(' . $unpack . '(' . $params . "))\n";
    }
    private function insertFastDecode($match) { return '{'.$this->buffer.';'; }
    private function insertFastEncode($match) { return '{$encode='.$this->buffer.';'; }
    private function getEncoder($ascii) { return $ascii>10?$ascii>36?$ascii>62?'encode95':'encode62':'encode36':'encode10'; }
    private function encode10($char_code) { return $char_code; }
    private function encode36($char_code) { return base_convert($char_code, 10, 36); }
    private function encode62($char_code) {
        $res = '';
        if ($char_code >= $this->encoding) { $res = $this->encode62((int)($char_code / $this->encoding)); }
        $char_code = $char_code % $this->encoding;
        if ($char_code > 35) { return $res . chr($char_code + 29); } else { return $res . base_convert($char_code, 10, 36); }
    }
    private function encode95($char_code) {
        $res = '';
        if ($char_code >= $this->encoding) { $res = $this->encode95($char_code / $this->encoding); }
        return $res . chr(($char_code % $this->encoding) + 161);
    }
    private function safeRegExp($string) { return '/'.preg_replace('/\$/', '\\\$', $string).'/'; }
    private function encodePrivate($char_code) { return "_" . $char_code; }
    private function escape($script) { return preg_replace('/([\\\\\'])/', '\\\$1', $script); }
    private function escape95($script) { return preg_replace_callback('/[\\xa1-\\xff]/', array(&$this, 'escape95Bis'), $script); }
    private function escape95Bis($match) { return '\x'.((string)dechex(ord($match))); }
    private function getJSFunction($aName) { if (defined('self::JSFUNCTION'.$aName)) { return constant('self::JSFUNCTION'.$aName); } else { return ''; } }
}

class ParseMaster {
    public $ignore_case     = false;
    public $escape_char     = '';
    const EXPRESSION        = 0;
    const REPLACEMENT       = 1;
    const LENGTH            = 2;
    private $GROUPS         = '/\\(/';
    private $SUB_REPLACE    = '/\\$\\d/';
    private $INDEXED        = '/^\\$\\d+$/';
    private $TRIM           = '/([\'"])\\1\\.(.*)\\.\\1\\1$/';
    private $ESCAPE         = '/\\\./';
    private $QUOTE          = '/\'/';
    private $DELETED        = '/\\x01[^\\x01]*\\x01/';
    private $escaped        = array();
    private $patterns       = array();
    private $buffer;
    public function add($expression, $replacement = '') {
        $length = 1 + preg_match_all($this->GROUPS, $this->internalEscape((string)$expression), $out);
        if (is_string($replacement)) {
            if (preg_match($this->SUB_REPLACE, $replacement)) {
                if (preg_match($this->INDEXED, $replacement)) { $replacement = (int)(substr($replacement, 1)) - 1; } else {
                    $quote          = preg_match($this->QUOTE, $this->internalEscape($replacement))?'"':"'";
                    $replacement    = array('fn' => 'backReferences', 'data' => array( 'replacement' => $replacement, 'length' => $length, 'quote' => $quote));
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($expression)) { $this->add_private($expression, $replacement, $length); } else { $this->add_private('/^$/', $replacement, $length); }
    }
    public function exec($string) {
        $this->escaped  = array();
        $regexp         = '/';
        foreach ($this->patterns as $reg) { $regexp .= '(' . substr($reg[self::EXPRESSION], 1, -1) . ')|'; }
        $regexp         = substr($regexp, 0, -1) . '/';
        $regexp .= ($this->ignore_case) ? 'i' : '';
        $string         = $this->escape($string, $this->escape_char);
        $string         = preg_replace_callback($regexp, array(&$this, 'replacement'), $string);
        $string         = $this->unescape($string, $this->escape_char);
        return preg_replace($this->DELETED, '', $string);
    }
    public function reset() { $this->patterns = array(); }
    private function add_private() {
        $arguments          = func_get_args();
        $this->patterns[]   = $arguments;
    }
    private function replacement($arguments) {
        if (empty($arguments)) { return ''; }
        $i = 1; $j = 0;
        while (isset($this->patterns[$j])) {
            $pattern = $this->patterns[$j++];
            if (isset($arguments[$i]) && ($arguments[$i] != '')) {
                $replacement = $pattern[self::REPLACEMENT];
                if (is_array($replacement) && isset($replacement['fn'])) {
                    if (isset($replacement['data'])) $this->buffer = $replacement['data'];
                    return call_user_func(array(&$this, $replacement['fn']), $arguments, $i);
                } elseif (is_int($replacement)) { return $arguments[$replacement + $i]; }
                $delete = ($this->escape_char == '' || strpos($arguments[$i], $this->escape_char) === false) ? '' : "\x01" . $arguments[$i] . "\x01";
                return $delete . $replacement;
            } else { $i += $pattern[self::LENGTH]; }
        }
    }
    private function backReferences($match, $offset) {
        $replacement    = $this->buffer['replacement'];
        $quote          = $this->buffer['quote'];
        $i              = $this->buffer['length'];
        while ($i) { $replacement = str_replace('$'.$i--, $match[$offset + $i], $replacement); }
        return $replacement;
    }
    private function replace_name($match, $offset){
        $length         = strlen($match[$offset + 2]);
        $start          = $length - max($length - strlen($match[$offset + 3]), 0);
        return substr($match[$offset + 1], $start, $length) . $match[$offset + 4];
    }
    private function replace_encoded($match, $offset) { return $this->buffer[$match[$offset]]; }
    private function escape($string, $escape_char) {
        if ($escape_char) {
            $this->buffer = $escape_char;
            return preg_replace_callback('/\\' . $escape_char . '(.)' .'/', array(&$this, 'escapeBis'), $string);
        } else { return $string; }
    }
    private function escapeBis($match) {
        $this->escaped[] = $match[1];
        return $this->buffer;
    }
    private function unescape($string, $escape_char) {
        if ($escape_char) {
            $regexp = '/'.'\\'.$escape_char.'/';
            $this->buffer = array('escapeChar'=> $escape_char, 'i' => 0);
            return preg_replace_callback($regexp, array(&$this, 'unescapeBis'), $string);
        } else { return $string; }
    }
    private function unescapeBis() {
        if (isset($this->escaped[$this->buffer['i']])&& $this->escaped[$this->buffer['i']] != '') { $temp = $this->escaped[$this->buffer['i']]; } else { $temp = ''; }
        $this->buffer['i']++;
        return $this->buffer['escapeChar'] . $temp;
    }
    private function internalEscape($string) { return preg_replace($this->ESCAPE, '', $string); }
}
```